# Python changing results of powershell command that is getting process memory usage

Tags: python, powershell, psutil

I am building a python script(running on windows) that checks on the memory usage of a java process and logs it. I first tried using psutil:

```
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        print(proc.name())
        if "java.exe" in proc.name():

            print("Process Found. Mem used: "+str((proc.memory_info().rss/1024/1024)
```

This returns 4095.99.. MB every time even though the actual memory usage as reported by task manager varies from 8100-8400 MB.

I then tried a Powershell command to do the same thing:

```
    powershell "Get-Process -Name java | SELECT WS"
```

where WS (working set) is the closest metric to what is reported by Task manager. Running that in a command terminal it returned a number within 20 MB of the processes current memory usage. I then tested running this command in python using subprocess:

```
     process = subprocess.Popen('powershell "Get-Process -Name java | SELECT WS "',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

     print(process.communicate()[0].strip())
```

and os.system:

```
    result = os.system('powershell "Get-Process -name java | SELECT WS"')
    print(result)
```

Both return the same 4095.99.. MB psutil did (down to the last digit.). So something about python is altering the way that it sees that processes memory. Have tried running it in several users including ones that are admins and the user that the process is running under all with the exact same results. I am stumped as to how python could be modifying the powershell call to have it return a different result than is run outside of it.

Comment: Do you have the same results when looking at other processes?  I ask because I ran your Python and Powershell examples against some of my processes and I got the expected results.  Nothing was altered.

Comment: No. My suspicion is it has to do with the amount of memory the java process is using. All the other processes I tested with were smaller than 1000mb of ram. It occurs to me that this is the 32 bit max value for integers(both psutil and the powershell command output the memory in bytes).

Comment: Which means the psutil issue could be caused by python not recognizing it needs to use a long. It doesn't explain the powershell though as that is returned back to python as a string though.

Comment: So, to verify, if you change the process name to something that uses less than 4 GB memory, it gives the correct value?

Comment: That is correct.